# jasmine how to test returned function

Tags: angularjs, unit-testing, typescript, jasmine

I try to test method like this:

```
method() {
  return service1.method1.then((result) => {
    if(result.val1 && result.val2) {
      return service2.method2.then(() =>{
        if() {
          return service3.method3().then(callback);
        }
      })
    }
  }
}
```

I just understand how to test call of `service1.method1` but how I can check another methods and conditions in them?

Please, give me direction, because I already tryed all I know^)